# Displaying data from a dataset vb.net

Tags: sql-server, wpf, vb.net, binding

I am having issues returning data from a MS SQL database.

The code is returning 'System.data.datarowview' instead of the results of my query. The code for the sub is:

```
    Public Sub newquery(query As String)
    Dim SQLConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
    Dim SqlCommand As New SqlCommand

    SQLConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\testing;Initial Catalog=eurostyle;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, SQLConn)

    Try
        SQLConn.Open()
        sqlDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand)
        sqlDataset = New DataSet
        sqlDA.Fill(sqlDataset)
        SQLConn.Close()
        listbox1.DataContext = sqlDataset
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

I am new to WPF and I'm sure that is only something trivial.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at any [Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx)?

Comment: I have, the code workings in a normal vb form but doesnt seem to work in wpf for some reason :-s. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/wpf-data-binding-in-vb.net
that is the tutorial that I read and modify that code still produces the same result.......

Comment: Do you use similar XAML?

Comment: Notice how there is a `DataTemplate` in the `Windows.Resources`? That is how they are binding the layout.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried to add the datatemplate into windows.resources but I keep getting errors, EG: Key attribute can be used only on a tag contained in an IDictionary type property

Comment: a DataGrid control may be more appropriate if you look for a simple tabular format. assign the souce like `dataGrid1.DataContext = sqlDataset.Tables[0].DefaultView`

Answer (score 1):

DataGrid view would be more appropriate to display results from database.

Try this:

```
Public Sub newquery(query As String)
    Dim SQLConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
    Dim SqlComm As New SqlCommand
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource
    Dim sqlDA As New SqlDataAdapter

    SQLConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\testing;Initial Catalog=eurostyle;Integrated Security=SSPI;"  

Try
     SQLConn.Open()
     SqlComm = SQLConn.CreateCommand
     SqlComm.CommandText = query

     SqlComm = New SqlCommand(zapytanie, myConn)
     sqlDA.SelectCommand = SqlComm
     sqlDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
     bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
     DataGridView.DataSource = bSource
     sqlDA.Update(dbDataSet)
     SQLConn.Close()

Catch ex As SqlException
     MessageBox.Show("Query Error: " & ex.Message)
End Try
```